# Passing parameters to a called form in C#

Tags: c#

This is my working example:

```
private void authentic_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     formauthentic accessmyauthenticform = new formauthentic();
     accessmyauthenticform.ShowDialog();
}
```

Now, how do you pass parameters to this called form, without re-inventing the code that you could of passed to it?

Thanks.

Comment: To all it may concern in answering my question(s). I went the "Communicate between two windows forms in C# (12 answers)" route (The FormCommunication.zip). I ran the C# 
 formcomm program and it took me a will while to catch on to what was going.  It was doing communication from form2 to form1. But I wanted communication to go from Form1 to Form2.  After understanding what was happening, I got the Form1 to form2 communication to work quite well and transferred the smarts and code over to my program, and now it works awesomely.  And now, A big Thanks for all who helped. Thanks. Papa Charlie.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you use properties defined in the form to get/set values

```
private void authentic_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Formauthentic accessmyauthenticform = new Formauthentic();
     accessmyauthenticform.UserName = "George";
     if(accessmyauthenticform.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
     {
         string token = accessmyauthenticform.Token;
     }
}
```